# Use breeze in regular MVC project instead of spa

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, breeze

breeze is a great library. Because of project complexity I don't want to use spa template. Is there a way I can use breeze in a regular .net mvc4 project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're releasing support for it very soon - directly in ASP.NET MVC and Visual Studio. Stay tuned...!

Comment: Microsoft just published these two Breeze templates this week: http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/breezeknockout-template http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/hottowel-template

Comment: We also have additional documentation on the templates here:
http://www.breezejs.com/spa-template?utm_source=ms-spa

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, just start with an empty .net MVC4 project and run the 'base' breeze nuget package ( the one that doesn't say 'sample').

Comment: My understanding is in order for breeze working I have to register routing for breeze. How about my regular mvc routing?

Comment: Your MVC routing is unaffected. Breeze only registers its Web API routes and does so by adding a *BreezeWebApiConfig.cs* to the *App_Start* folder via the "breeze.WebApi" NuGet package. These are starting places. FWIW, I routinely begin my own projects from "MVC 4 Empty"

Comment: MVC routes and Web API routes are different. Confusing? Yes.